# Sending Hotkeys

Tags: c#, .net

I tried to send Hotkey "alt X" with a template I found in c# programming guide but nither message is shown nor HotKey was sent to Jcpicker. I am going to gather aprox. 1000 colors from an image as file of strings for further analising so I am asking community what's wrong in this code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {}

        // Clicking Button1 causes a message box to appear.
        void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            
            => MessageBox.Show("Click here!");

       
        // Use the SendKeys.Send method to raise the Button1 click event 
        // and display the message box.
        void Form1_DoubleClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            {

                // Send the enter key; since the tab stop of Button1 is 0, this
                // will trigger the click event.
                SendKeys.Send(keys: "%{X}");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, "it doesn't work" isn't enough of a problem description for us to help.

Comment: SendKeys only sends keypresses to the active application.  Is Jcipicker active when you doubleclick on your form? (Hint: no--your form is the active application).

Comment: Take a look at [InputSimulatorStandard (MIT License)](https://github.com/GregsStack/InputSimulatorStandard)